# Doing a Natural Join on Two Tables in two Different Databases

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement, natural-join

I have two tables: p.Test and q.Test on two different Databases - p and q.

Both these tables have different MYSQL connections and are on two different servers.

I need to do a Natural Join as is given here : http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/comparing-data-from-2-database-tables/2/

How do I possibly do that? I am using java PreparedStatement as well to actually run the query. Is there a way to possibly do this?

Say I create two Connections to each of them:

```
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URLtoPDB, Username,Password);
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URLtoQDB, Username,Password);
```

How do I fire a preparedStatement to even do say: `select * from p.Test,q.Test`

Comment: *Why* do you need a Natural Join on Two Tables in two Different Databases?

Comment: To find out the difference in rows.

Comment: I have this replicated table in my database from another one that I only have read access to. I need to check for any difference in row-data between them. I thought this was a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the database name before the table name  in query as below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [yourdatabase1].[jajal].[j]
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN [yourdatabase2].[jajal_copy] jc
WHERE
     jc.user_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
   *
FROM
    [yourdatabase1].[jajal].[j]
NATURAL RIGHT JOIN [yourdatabase2].[jajal_copy] jc
WHERE
    j.user_id IS NULL
```

you can user servernames for different servers as

```
 select
    *
 from
    LocalTable,
      [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]
```

Comment: Will this work even if DB1 and DB2 are on different servers and require different connections?

Comment: For cross server you can specify the server names in query

Comment: Hmmm.... including the UserName and PassWord? OR will I have to be connected beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

From comments in other answers, it looks like you need to compare two tables from different database servers. In that case, you have to use [federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html). This is a change that has to be done on the database server. You can't do that in your Java code.

If you have to do it in Java and you cannot modify anything in the database, you have to download all the data to memory and compare them manually.

Comment: Any efficient way to do this? How about getting all the data in two Hashmaps and comparing them? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721735/how-to-receive-difference-of-maps-in-java

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to setup [database replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) to keep your tables in sync, so you don't have to care about it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Do your replica again, into another table of current database and then compare.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mysql then database is equivalent to schema.
so it is straight forward

```
select * 
from p.Test natural join q.Test;
```

Comment: Can they be in totally different Databases?

Comment: yes if they are in same mysql instance. and you don't even need two connection

Comment: So, If I use a different connection to each of them... It won't work?