# Compare 2 nearly identical maps and find key of value that differate

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

So I have two identical maps with String as key and Integer as value and I know that after certain event only 1 value in map2 increment by 1.

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("First", 1)
map1.put("Second", 2)
map1.put("Third", 3)
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("First", 1)
map2.put("Second", 3)
map2.put("Third", 3)
```

So my question is how I can return "Second" key because its value is incremented by 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721735/how-to-receive-difference-of-maps-in-java/24814200 does this answer your question?

Comment: @Andreas Not really because both maps have same keys, so method given in provided question will always return empty map.

Comment: Please have a second look (and at least try the proposed solution). Guava `Maps.difference` returns the diff in two maps. If you call `entriesDiffering` on the returned `MapDifference` you get what you asked for.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, but I would not import whole library just for a simple task like this, anyway i found solution by using stream and filter options. 
`Map<String, Integer> razlika = map1.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey()))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to receive difference of maps in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721735/how-to-receive-difference-of-maps-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

The stream pipeline in your answer works, but might be more complex than necessary. Essentially it's performing a difference operation on the sets of entries of each map. You can do this using the collections bulk operation `removeAll` instead of a stream, like so:

```
// setup
var map1 = Map.of("First", 1, "Second", 2, "Third", 3);
var map2 = Map.of("First", 1, "Second", 3, "Third", 3);

// compute difference of entry sets
var difference = new HashMap<>(map1);
difference.entrySet().removeAll(map2.entrySet());

difference ==> {Second=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to get the keys and without the values, so the following method will do exactly that.

```java
public static <K> List mapDifference(Map<? extends K, ? extends Object> map1, Map<? extends K, ? extends Object> map2)
{
        List<K> keys = new ArrayList<K>();
        Set<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends Object>> set;
        Map<? extends K, ? extends Object> other;
        if(map1.size() > map2.size()) {
            set = map1.entrySet(); other = map2;
        } else {
            set = map2.entrySet(); other = map1;
        }
        Iterator<Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends Object>> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<? extends K, ?  extends Object> entry = iterator.next();
            K key = entry.getKey();
            if(!other.containsKey(key) || !other.get(key).equals(entry.getValue())) {
                keys.add(key);
            }
        }
        return keys;
}
```

**TESTS**

```java
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("First", 1);
map1.put("Second", 2);
map1.put("Third", 3);
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("First", 1);
map2.put("Second", 3);
map2.put("Third", 3);

List<String> diff = mapDifference(map1, map2);
System.out.println(diff);
```

```
[Second]
```

```java
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("First", 1);
map1.put("Second", 2);
map1.put("Third", 3);
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("First", 1);
map2.put("Second", 3);
map2.put("Third", 3);
map2.put("Forth", 4);

List<String> diff = mapDifference(map1, map2);
System.out.println(diff);
```

```
[Second, Forth]
```

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> razlika = map1.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey()))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));` is far more simple

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<String, Integer> difference = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.